# ignoring duplicate duplicate broadcasts does not works

Tags: android

In my android application I am sending SMS on receiving SIM_STATE_CHANGE broadcast. I have used `static boolean duplicate_broadcast` variable in my code to ignore duplicate broadcast but still I am receiving two messages on SIM_STATE_CHANGE event (when I restart my phone). I have double checked that both the broadcasts are of type `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED`. So please tell what is problem in my code?

**Code:**

```
public class BroadcastHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static boolean duplicate_broadcast = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(duplicate_broadcast ==false) {
            duplicate_broadcast = true;
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("messageAddress", null, "messageBody", null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastHandler">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Try putting the section of code in `onReceive` under a `synchronised` block